# Why Integer has "compare" method and string have "compareTo" method in java

Tags: java

I am intrigued by the fact I noticed today
that for comparision in java

**Integer provides compare** method
`Integer.compare(student1.age, student2.age);`

**String provides compareTo** Method
`Student1.firstName.compareTo(student2.firstName);`

Just want to understand why so :/

Please refer example class here:

```
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    long studentId;

    Student(){}
    Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age, long studentId){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
}
```

Camparator Implementations -

```
public class StudentFirstNameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
        return student1.firstName.compareTo(student2.firstName);
    }
}
```

```
public class StudentAgeComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
         return Integer.compare(student1.age, student2.age);

            //          either of the lines can be used.
//        if(student1.age == student2.age)
//            return 0;
//        else if (student1.age>student2.age) {
//            return 1;
//        }else {
//            return -1;
//        }
   
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Integer` also has a `compareTo(...)` method](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)). This, however, will not help (directly) in this case since an `int` is a primitive, not an object.

Comment: And note that `Integer` **does not** implement `java.util.Comparator`. It simply has a static `compare(int, int)` method for comparing _primitives_ (i.e., `int`s) instead of the reference types (i.e., `Integer`s). The other reference types for primitives (e.g., `Double`, `Long`, etc.) have similar methods, but for their respective associated primitives.

Answer (score 5):

The `Integer` class also provides a [`compareTo` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)), because it's `Comparable` like `String` is.

Take a look at `Integer` class's [`compare` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)), and notice that it has 2 `int` arguments and it's `static`.  This way, one can compare two primitive `int`s safely without boxing them into `Integer`s, which is what would occur with `compareTo`.